# Page Load event does not fire inside JavaScript modal pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an aspx page which I am showing inside a JavaScript pop up like this.

When client side button clicked in the parent page, JavaScript fires to display the pop up.

```
function shoeColOptions() {

    var saveColPref = document.getElementById("hdnSaveColPref").value;
    var colResult = window.showModalDialog("ColumnPreference.aspx?prefPattern=" + saveColPref, "Select Columns", 'center:yes; dialogWidth:600px; dialogHeight:250px; location:no; edge:raised; help:no; resizable:no; scroll:no; status:no; statusbar:no; toolbar:no; menubar:no; addressbar:no; titlebar:no;');

    if ((colResult != "") && (colResult != "undefined")) {

        var hdnCol = document.getElementById("hdnColPref");
        hdnCol.value = colResult;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }        

}
```

There is some code to populate few drop down lists in the `Page_Load` event in the aspx page.

The problem is, the page load event in the `ColumnPreference.aspx` page fires only the first time. If I close the pop up and open it again, the Page_Load event does not fire, hence the drop down lists in the pop up is not updated.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For your understanding Please note that `PageLoad()` will trigger only when the page post back. If your button click event not post back the page then `Pageload()` method not to be call.

Please share your `PageLoad()` code So that I can improve my answer.

Comment: Hi Dhana, the button click javascripts loads a model dialog window inside which my aspx page is being loaded. The button is in the parent page. The load event I am concerned about in in the child page. The page load event should autometically fire every time the pop up opens is not it?